# Presto SQL - How can i get all possible combination of an array?

Tags: arrays, database, hive, presto

I want all the possible combination of a number in a given set of array.

I tried using some of the predefined functions of presto like array_agg(x)

```
Input : [1,2,3,4]
Output
when n=2 : [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4],[3,4]]
when n=3 : [[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,3,4],[2,3,4]]
when n=4 : [[1,2,3,4]] or [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: It's beyond SQL's power.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [combinations(array(T), n)](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#combinations)  function and it does exactly what you want:

```
select combinations(array[1,2,3,4],2);
```

Comment: Thanks you so much